# how $\pi$ is irrational if it is a ratio

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi

> How can $\pi$ be an irrational number if it is a ratio of the circumference over the diameter?

Thanks!

Comment: Circumference and diameter are not both integers.

Comment: Please write down the question normally...and why being a ratio would be an obstacle for $\;\pi\;$ to be irrational?

Comment: Irrational = Not the ratio of two integers.

Answer (score 7):

I can write **any** real number $\alpha$ as a ratio: $\frac\alpha1.$

What makes a number *rational* is when can be written as a ratio of *integers* (with the denominator non-zero).

---

See [this comic](http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2208#comic) for all that needs to be said on the subject.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This answers the question clearly and concisely.